# Symfony: compare passwords with StringUtils::equals

Tags: php, symfony

I want to compare submitted `password` and `passwordConfirm` values with `StringUtils::equals` in Symfony. The thing is, I don't have the `passwordConfirm` field in my User Entity class (as I've read somewhere,  it's not a good practice).

My question is, where would it be best to place my passwords comparison using `StringUtils::equals` function? Is it in Controller?

Comment: Why won't you use [repeated field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html)?

Comment: I have read about it, and the way I understand it is that it's used in the Form Builder. But I am writing my own view in html.twig

Comment: You can render some of the form's components manually if you need/want to. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html